# Flash builder 4.6 Fake flex error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a problem with flash builder 4.6

Its giving me a fake error and I don't know how to fix it.
Its telling me this:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type GuisP:OptionsMenu to an unrelated type GUIs:GUI.
```

Given this method:

```
public function setCurrentGUI(gui:Gui):void
```

Using this class:

```
public class OptionsMenu extends Gui
```

And I know its a fake error because if I restart Flash Builder it will just run and throw no errors at all.

I should probably add that I'm using the Appache 4.10.0 Flex SDK

Is there any way to fix this Without having to restart flash builder every 5 minutes?

Comment: Have you tried a project clean?  Are all your libraries compiled with Apache Flex 4.10?  I've seen odd errors by mixing and matching SWCs compiled w/ different versions of Flex.  Do you have two classes named OptionsMenu; potentially causing an ambiguous reference?

Comment: I'll look into this, I'll let you know.

No, I don't have to classes named the same (or packages named the same as a class)

Comment: Also, to my knowledge, the Apache Flex SDK isn't supported by Flash Builder 4.6, you have to upgrade to Flash Builder 4.7. Yes, you'll lose design view in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you to Project > Clean... that usually fixes the errors for me. 
If that doesn't work you can try creating a new file with the same name and moving over the code. I've had to do that before.